# How do I make a visual inventory in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a small game in which I need a five to six slot inventory, which basically looks something like this [  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ], and in each of those boxes, an item needs to be placed. Currently, I have tried using dictionaries but they have not gotten me what I want. A list of what I want in it: a 6 slot inventory which puts anything (ex: a rectangle) in the first open slot. If a key is pressed, the item in the slot most to the right which has an item in it will disappear, and when a different key is pressed, it should put an item in the first open slot. I just want someone to send me in the right direction and tell me what will be useful for creating an inventory working this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with pygame but I am familiar with python so hopefully this is helpful..

Sounds like you need to make a list that operates as a [stack](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-data-structure/)

```
inv = []
```

Code below will add an item to that list.

```
if len(inv) < 6:
    inv.append(item)
else:
    print("No inventory space")
```

This code will remove the most recently added item:

```
inv.pop()
```

.pop() removes the most recently added item in a list in python.  At which point the person can attempt to re-add the previous item into the space and it should go into space 6 (which in the list is inv[5] since lists count 0 as the first slot).

EDIT 1 for comment reply:
    import pygame, sys
    pygame.init()

```
inv = []
#Code below will add an item to that list.
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

    key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_x]:
            if len(inv) < 6:
                    inv.append("someItem")              
            else:
                    print("No inventory space")
#This code will remove the most recently added item:
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_z]:
            inv.pop()
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_c]:
            print(inv)
```

Comment: It seems as it should work but testing with this code and nothing happens. 
https://pastebin.com/RtPWHLVa

Comment: You need to specify an item.  Just doing inv.append(item) is trying to append an object without anything attached to it.  Which won't work.  For printing inventory, simply use print(inv).  I've updated my initial response so you can see the code easier.

Comment: Ah okay, but I still have a major problem. When I click x, the console says no inventory space 20 + times. When I print the contents of inv, i get ['someItem', 'someItem', 'someItem', 'someItem', 'someItem', 'someItem'] around 20 times, and when i try to pop, i get an error 'can not pop from empty list. Not sure why it is repeating itself or why it is an empty list, can you explain why?

Comment: pygame.key.get_pressed() will register many times per second, that's why the list is immediately getting filled and printing many times. Use the pygame event KEYDOWN instead.

Comment: inv.pop() should print out what item is being removed.  We should check that by using print("Pop successful") after inv.pop().  Meanwhile, change all of your key_pressed to KEYDOWN like @DinosauRuss said, then see if it happens.  My guess is it's popping everything extremely quickly and then it gets to an empty list and starts giving you that error.  It might also not be printing out the removed items.  Implement both and then test again.

Comment: Alright it's working, thanks so much for the help and I plan to use it moving forward in making it visual

Comment: Glad I could help, hope to get 5 stars on yelp.

Comment: so say I dont want to actually delete the spot when I remove it-- would doing inv[x] is None work also?

Comment: What do you mean by "delete the spot", the inventory space still exists to be refilled.  inv[x] is None just checks if there is something in that slot in the list.  "is" is a boolean operator for true / false in python.